# API endpoint using 'subprocess' to start parallel runs of a large python model

Tags: python, api, parallel-processing, subprocess

I am trying to build an API (using FastAPI), where one of the endpoints uses subprocess to start parallel runs of a large python model (the output of which will become available on a 'data pickup' location).

When I send the POST request to start a new model run, everything works perfectly and I see the data appear after the run. However, when I send a second request directly after triggering a first run, I would like this to trigger a parallel run of the same process. Instead, the new run now overwrites the earlier triggered process, and I only see model output appear for the latest model run. Is there a way to handle this with subprocesses?

I wasn't expected this to happen. I thought that since the subprocess is activated by the create_run() function a second instance of this function wouldn't have access to / be able to overwrite an earlier instance of the same function that is still running.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import nest_asyncio
import uvicorn
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

#include all of our API nodes here
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/index')
async def home():
  return "Hello World"
#exec(open('api.py').read())

@app.post("/run")
async def create_run():
    out_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    err_file = open("log.txt", "w")
    process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "model.py"]
                    , stdout = out_file, stderr = err_file)
    return "run started. Data will be available on pickup location"
```

Comment: The `out_file` and `err_file` are static, so they will be overwritten each request to /run.

Comment: My problem was not that the log files were being overwritten (which are indeed named statically), but that the dynamically named output generated by model.py was overwritten as well. Nevertheless, thank you very much; your comment made me double-check this, and I found out that when the process is triggered multiple times it initiates the same dynamic name for the output files (leading to the overwrite in the output). Addressing this allowed me to fix it.